# Sails + react on a single heroku server ?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, sails.js

I have a single project which runs sails app on 1337 port and react on 3000. How can I deploy both to single heroku instance ? Which runs sails on 1337 and react on 3000.

Answer (score 2):

You need to integrate React with Sails.

React is all about static files (e.g. HTML, JS and CSS). To integrate React with Sails, a naive solution is to copy the compiled React files to the Sails `assets` folder.

Below is what I have tried with a brand new Sails app. It just works.

1. Edit `config/blueprints.js` to change the API prefix. From now on, the APIs changes from `http://localhost:1337/<RESOURCE>` to `http://localhost:1337/api/<RESOURCE>`.

```js
module.exports.blueprints = {
  // ...
  
  prefix: '/api',
  
  // ...
}
```

2. Edit `config/routes.js`. Remove the following lines if they exist. This makes sure that when someone visit `http://localhost:1337`, Sails will search for `index.html` inside the `assets` folder.

```js
'/': {
  view: 'homepage'
}
```

3. Update the React application in case it consumes the APIs from Sails (Remember that we have changed the API prefix). Also make sure that the application entry point is `index.html`.
4. Compile your React application (by Webpack or Grunt or whatever packaging tool you are using) and copy the compiled files to the Sails `assets` folder.
5. Deploy the Sails app to Heroku.
6. Done!

A better but more tedious solution is to migrate the React development to Sails. I found [an example](https://github.com/mixxen/sails-react-example) on Google. It might be outdated because the last update was Feb 2016, but you shall use it as a reference.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks, dude :)